# Extracting first occurrence of number after specific keyword, for each instance of keyword (Python)

Tags: python, regex, string, text, extract

I'm relatively new at Python and still learning the basics of dataframes and text extraction.

I have a column of strings that may or may not contain the keyword "discount rate" several times. When "discount rate" is there, I would like to grab the FIRST set of numbers that come after that word, and put those into a new column as a string. The numbers don't always appear *immediately* after the word "rate" appears, sometimes there may be a word or two in between.

I'm looking for a way to grab this text for ALL instances of "discount rate".

Currently, my code is only grabbing all occurrences of number ranges, but I only want the ones after "discount rate". Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
df["ext"] = ""
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df["ext"][i] = str(set(re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+%',df.loc[i,'txt']))).strip()
```

The output of this code gives me a set of strings - which I am later splitting into multiple columns - like this:

```
{'13.0%', '3.5%', '2.5%', '11.0%'}
```

For reference, the strings usually look something like this:

```
...growth rates of 2.5% to 3.5% to xxx calendar year 2025 after-tax 
free cash flows. Xxx alsoperformed a discounted cash flow 
analysis of the xxx to calculate the present value of the after-tax xxxx that 
xxx forecasted would be generated during calendar years 2015(using only the 
fourth quarter of 2015) through 2025 and of the terminal value of the xxxx by 
applying perpetuity growth rates of 1.0% to 2.0% to the calendar year 2025 
after-tax free cash flows. The cash flows andterminal values were discounted 
to present value as of September 30,2015 using discount rates ranging from 
9.50% to 12.50%, which were based on an estimate of xxxs weighted average 
cost of capital. This analysis indicated thefollowing approximate implied per 
share equity value reference ranges for xxx as compared to the Merger 
Consideration....
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only make the code specific to the sample text you provided.

```
sample_text = '''...growth rates of 2.5% to 3.5% to xxx calendar year 2025 after-tax 
free cash flows. Xxx alsoperformed a discounted cash flow 
analysis of the xxx to calculate the present value of the after-tax xxxx that 
xxx forecasted would be generated during calendar years 2015(using only the 
fourth quarter of 2015) through 2025 and of the terminal value of the xxxx by 
applying perpetuity growth rates of 1.0% to 2.0% to the calendar year 2025 
after-tax free cash flows. The cash flows andterminal values were discounted 
to present value as of September 30,2015 using discount rates ranging from 
9.50% to 12.50%, which were based on an estimate of xxxs weighted average 
cost of capital. This analysis indicated thefollowing approximate implied per 
share equity value reference ranges for xxx as compared to the Merger 
Consideration....'''

split_sample_text = sample_text.split()

discount_ranges = list()
for index, word in enumerate(split_sample_text):
    if word == "discount" and  split_sample_text[index + 1] == "rates":
        start_rate = None
        end_rate = None

        for index_, rate in enumerate(split_sample_text[index + 2:]):
            if "%" in rate:
                try:
                    float(rate.rstrip("%,"))
                    if not start_rate:
                        start_rate = rate
                    elif not end_rate:
                        end_rate = rate.rstrip(',')
                except ValueError:
                    pass

            elif rate == "discount" and split_sample_text[index_ + 1:] == "rates":
                break

        if start_rate and end_rate:
            discount_ranges.append((start_rate, end_rate))

print discount_ranges
```

Gives us:

```
[('9.50%', '12.50%')]
```

If you paste your sample text 3x, it will still extract this same discount rate thrice, Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your input. I ended up doing something a bit different, but I liked your method as well. What I did was split each string in the column on all instances of the word "discount," and then searched each new string for the numbers I was looking for. I also partitioned the new strings where there was "growth" rates included, so that only discount rate ranges were grabbed.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)